# Reinf - Erro com evento R-5011

Tags: c#, xml, web-service

Ao tentar assinar o evento de consulta R-5011, estou me deparando com esse erro:

> “O elemento ‘http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/evtTotalContrib/v1_03_00:nrProtEntr' é inválido – O valor ‘4308-2099-1701-4308’ é inválido dependendo do tipo de dados ‘String’ – O comprimento atual não é igual ao comprimento especificado.”

Esse é o xml do evento antes de assinar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Reinf xmlns="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/evtTotalContrib/v1_03_00">
    <evtTotalContrib id="ID1102200480000002018041218075500001">
        <ideEvento>
            <perApur>2017-01</perApur>
        </ideEvento>
        <ideContri>
            <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>
            <nrInsc>10220048</nrInsc>
        </ideContri>
        <ideRecRetorno>
            <ideStatus>
                <cdRetorno>2</cdRetorno>
                <descRetorno>EM PROCESSAMENTO</descRetorno>
            </ideStatus>
        </ideRecRetorno>
        <infoRecEv>
            <nrProtEntr>4308-2099-1701-4308</nrProtEntr>
            <dhProcess>2018-04-12T18:07:55</dhProcess>
            <tpEv>2099</tpEv>
            <idEv>ID1102200480000002018040914443600001</idEv>
            <hash>Wh6iWTlvKY+tApuALf0IFC0+u86EulO4oUNjTF6R/mY=</hash>
        </infoRecEv>
        <infoTotalContrib>
            <nrRecArqBase>4308-05-2099-1701-4308</nrRecArqBase>
            <indExistInfo>3</indExistInfo>
        </infoTotalContrib>
    </evtTotalContrib>
</Reinf>
```

Alguém poderia me dizer como corrigir isso?

Comment: O erro está dando ao assinar o XML, como você disse na pergunta, ou ao enviar o evento para o WebService do EFD-Reinf? Se for ao assinar, coloca o trecho de código que você está usando para assinar o evento para tentarmos descobrir o que pode ser.

Comment: Para postar XML aqui no SO, basta colar o código XML, seleciona-lo e clicar na imagem `{}` (_Amostra de código <pre> <code> Ctrl+K_) na barra de edição acima da caixa de texto onde você escreve a pergunta. E, para que o SO formate corretamente o XML, coloque a tag `xml` na sua pergunta (eu já editei e fiz essas alterações).

Comment: Entendi a situação errado, o evento 5011 não precisa - nem deve - ser assinado, mesmo porque não vai ser transmitido. Mesmo assim, esse erro ocorre antes da assinatura

Comment: Verdade, na pressa eu nem me atentei a esse detalhe também, até porque estou mais envolvido com o eSocial do que com o EFD-Reinf no momento, mas, se for o mesmo esquema do eSocial, esse evento provavelmente será recebido apenas, não será enviado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois das mensagens que trocamos nos comentários, eu fiz uma pesquisa aqui e vi que realmente esse evento **R-5011** (*"Informações de bases e tributos consolidadas por período de apuração"*, com nome `evtTotalContrib`, definido no arquivo *'retornoTotalizadorContribuinte-v1_03_02.xsd'*) realmente é apenas um evento de retorno, ou seja, você não precisa preenche-lo, assina-lo e envia-lo, é o EFD-Reinf que preencherá, assinará e retornará para você esse evento, na consulta.

Eu demorei um pouco para entender a consulta (que eles liberaram a pouco tempo), porque o esquema dela é um pouco diferente do eSocial, e do próprio WebService de envio do EFD-Reinf.

Não sei se você já sabe, e se já escreveu a rotina para fazer a consulta, mas, o endereço para acessar o WebService de consulta do EFD-Reinf é esse aqui:

> *Ambiente de Produção Restrita (teste):*
>   https://preprodefdreinf.receita.fazenda.gov.br/WsReinfConsultas/ConsultasReinf.svc
>
> *Ambiente de Produção (oficial):*
>   https://reinf.receita.fazenda.gov.br/WsReinfConsultas/ConsultasReinf.svc

E o endereço do WSDL, para adicionar uma referência ao serviço de consulta no seu projeto, é esse aqui:

> *Ambiente de Produção Restrita (teste):*
>   https://preprodefdreinf.receita.fazenda.gov.br/WsReinfConsultas/ConsultasReinf.svc?singleWsdl
>
> *Ambiente de Produção (oficial):*
>   https://reinf.receita.fazenda.gov.br/WsReinfConsultas/ConsultasReinf.svc?singleWsdl

Mas o WSDL do serviço de consulta também pode ser baixado desse outro endereço:

> http://sped.rfb.gov.br/arquivo/show/2548

Eu notei que os parâmetros de entrada para o serviço de consulta já estão definidos diretamento no WSDL, e não em um arquivo .XSD a parte, como no caso do eSocial e do serviço de envio do EFD-Reinf:

```
<wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://sped.fazenda.gov.br/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <xs:element name="ConsultaInformacoesConsolidadas">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="tipoInscricaoContribuinte" type="xs:unsignedByte"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="numeroInscricaoContribuinte" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="numeroProtocoloFechamento" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        [...]
    </xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

Então criei um projeto de teste, adicionei a referência ao serviço (chamei o namespace do serviço adicionado de **WsConsultas**) e verifiquei que a consulta ficaria assim:

```c#
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Xml.Linq;

// [...]

// Acessando o serviço no ambiente de Produção Restrita (teste).
var urlServicoConsulta =
  @"https://preprodefdreinf.receita.fazenda.gov.br/WsReinfConsultas/ConsultasReinf.svc";
var address = new EndpointAddress(urlServicoConsulta);
var binding = new BasicHttpsBinding();  //Disponível desde .NET Framework 4.5
// ou:
//var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport);
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;

// Instancia o cliente para acessar o serviço de consulta do EFD-Reinf.
var wsClient = new WsConsultas.ConsultasReinfClient(binding, address);
wsClient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = x509Cert;

byte tipoInscricaoContribuinte = 1;
string numeroInscricaoContribuinte = "10220048";
string numeroProtocoloFechamento = "4308-2099-1701-4308";
// Solicita uma consulta, passando os parâmetros
// e recebendo o evento R-5011 como retorno.
XElement retornoTotalContrib = 
            wsClient.ConsultaInformacoesConsolidadas(
                 tipoInscricaoContribuinte, 
                 numeroInscricaoContribuinte,
                 numeroProtocoloFechamento);
wsClient.Close();
```

Você pode ler um pouco mais sobre esse serviço de consulta no **Manual de Orientação ao Desenvolvedor v1.3**, da página 43 à pagina 53:

> http://sped.rfb.gov.br/arquivo/download/2523