# C# - EFD Reinf v1_04_00 - retornoEventos - nrProtEntr - Tratamento do Retorno

Tags: c#, web-service

Após conseguir enviar com sucesso o evento R1000, através das perguntas:

- [C# - EFD Reinf v1_04_00 - Como instanciar e preencher todas propriedades dos Eventos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/348614/c-efd-reinf-v1-04-00-como-instanciar-e-preencher-todas-propriedades-dos-eve)
- [Como consumir WebService do EFD-Reinf no C#? (Envio Eventos)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/343132/como-consumir-webservice-do-efd-reinf-no-c-envio-eventos)

Obtive o retorno na variável e preciso tratá-lo:

```
var retornoEnvioXElement = wsClient.ReceberLoteEventos(doc.Root);
```

? retornoEnvioXElement

```
{<Reinf xmlns="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/retornoLoteEventos/v1_04_00">
  <retornoLoteEventos id="IDF4EBD1BA1DDE6A0B288DD85C8DF1E535">
    <ideTransmissor>
      <IdTransmissor>01628604000140</IdTransmissor>
    </ideTransmissor>
    <status>
      <cdStatus>0</cdStatus>
      <descRetorno>SUCESSO</descRetorno>
    </status>
    <retornoEventos>
      <evento id="ID1016286040000002018121309305100001">
        <Reinf xmlns="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/evtTotal/v1_04_00">
          <evtTotal id="ID-1066770329">
            <ideEvento>
              <perApur />
            </ideEvento>
            <ideContri>
              <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>
              <nrInsc>01628604</nrInsc>
            </ideContri>
            <ideRecRetorno>
              <ideStatus>
                <cdRetorno>0</cdRetorno>
                <descRetorno>SUCESSO</descRetorno>
              </ideStatus>
            </ideRecRetorno>
            <infoRecEv>
              <dhProcess>2018-12-13T09:31:39.1306938-02:00</dhProcess>
              <tpEv>1000</tpEv>
              <idEv>ID1016286040000002018121309305100001</idEv>
              <hash>dw94b8lBK83zUyVwc6p8obI8F1fc/Ag0NkU2QHWi/Og=</hash>
            </infoRecEv>
            <infoTotal>
              <nrRecArqBase>14009-04-1000-1812-14009</nrRecArqBase>
              <ideEstab>
                <tpInsc>0</tpInsc>
              </ideEstab>
            </infoTotal>
          </evtTotal>
          <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <SignedInfo>
              <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
              <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
              <Reference URI="#ID-1066770329">
                <Transforms>
                  <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                  <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
                </Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                <DigestValue>sfY6hV4oPUQhpjcLMZa61Odj8xEQOvAdyLXJOYfvS4g=</DigestValue>
              </Reference>
            </SignedInfo>
            <SignatureValue>[...]</SignatureValue>
            <KeyInfo>
              <X509Data>
                <X509Certificate>[...]</X509Certificate>
              </X509Data>
            </KeyInfo>
          </Signature>
        </Reinf>
      </evento>
    </retornoEventos>
  </retornoLoteEventos>
</Reinf>}
```

Pergunto:
Quais campos devo armazenar para posteriores consultas do que foi já foi enviado?

Eu estava esperando o `nrProtEntr` "Número do protocolo de entrega do evento", mas ele não veio neste retorno. É isso mesmo?

Apenas a `<hash>dw94b8lBK83zUyVwc6p8obI8F1fc/Ag0NkU2QHWi/Og=</hash>` é suficiente para no futuro recuperar Recibos de Entrega?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O campo `nrProtEntr` é retornado somente quando há o envio do evento de fechamento R-2099 (veja [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/291189/86952) como consultar o retorno desse evento), no caso dos outros eventos o campo que você deve pegar é o `nrRecArqBase`.

Para tratar o retorno, esse objeto `XElement` pode ser "de-serializado" para uma [classe gerada pela ferramenta XSD.exe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/347877/86952), através dos XSDs do [Pacote de Comunicação EFD-Reinf v1.04.00](http://sped.rfb.gov.br/arquivo/show/2803), usando essas funções:

```
// Pode ser usado para XDocument, XElement, XContainer, XNode.
public T DeserializeFromXNode<T>(XNode xNode)
{
   using (var reader = xNode.CreateReader())
   {
      var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
      return (T)xs.Deserialize(reader);
   }
}

// Pode ser usado para XmlDocument, XmlElement, XmlNode e outros.
public T DeserializeFromXmlNode<T>(XmlNode xmlNode)
{
   using (var reader = new XmlNodeReader(xmlNode))
   {
      var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
      return (T)xs.Deserialize(reader);
   }
}
```

Que podem ser usadas dessa forma:

```
var retornoEnvio = DeserializeFromXNode<RetornoLoteEventos.Reinf>(retornoEnvioXElement);
var eventos = retornoEnvio?.retornoLoteEventos.retornoEventos?.evento;

foreach (var retornoEvtXml in eventos)
{
   var retornoEvt = DeserializeFromXmlNode<RetornoTotalizadorEvento.Reinf>(retornoEvtXml.Any);
   if (retornoEvt.evtTotal.ideRecRetorno.ideStatus.cdRetorno != 0)
      continue;
   var nrRecibo = retornoEvt.evtTotal.infoTotal?.nrRecArqBase;
   var hash = retornoEvt.evtTotal.infoRecEv.hash;
}
```

Sobre a necessidade ou não de guardar o campo `hash`, o [Manual de Orientação ao Desenvolvedor da EFD-Reinf v1.4](http://sped.rfb.gov.br/arquivo/show/2897) diz o seguinte, na página 32:

> Para que seja possível a recuperação do número do recibo o evento deve ser reenviado ao
>   ambiente nacional seguindo as seguintes premissas:
>
> a) O evento deve ser o mesmo enviado anteriormente;
>   b) Deve possuir o mesmo HASH;
>   c) Deve ser mantido o mesmo ID do que foi enviado na primeira tentativa;

Então pode ser uma boa ideia armazenar esse campo, sim.

Comment: Dúvida:
na linha:
var retornoEnvio = DeserializeFromXNode<RetornoLoteEventos.Reinf>(retornoEnvioXElement);
o "RetornoLoteEventos" é o namespace certo? Eu criei desta forma...

                                       
Está me retornando o seguinte erro:
na linha return (T)xs.Deserialize(reader) da function DeserializeFromXNode<T>;

Retorna o seguinte erro:
System.InvalidOperationException: 'There is an error in XML document (0, 0).'

Exceção Interna:

InvalidOperationException: <Reinf xmlns='http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/retornoLoteEventos/v1_04_00'> was not expected.

Comment: ? (T)xs.Deserialize(reader);
'(T)xs.Deserialize(reader)' gerou uma exceção do tipo 'System.InvalidOperationException'
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HResult: -2146233079
    HelpLink: null
    InnerException: {"<Reinf xmlns='http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/retornoLoteEventos/v1_04_00'> was not expected."}
    Message: "There is an error in XML document (0, 0)."
    Source: "System.Xml"
    StackTrace: "   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)\r\n   at ...

Comment: Isso, nesse caso `RetornoLoteEventos` é o namespace. Qual o conteúdo da variável de retorno `retornoEnvioXElement` quando você passa o mouse em cima, no *debug*? Tem algo ou está vazio?

Comment: Na classe `Reinf` que foi gerada pela ferramenta 'XSD.exe', para o schema `retornoLoteEventos`, o valor do parâmetro `Namespace`, do atributo `XmlTypeAttribute`, está como? É o mesmo valor que está aí no erro, e no XML de retorno? Pelo *schema* oficial, o valor deveria ser `"http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/retornoLoteEventos/v1_04_00"`.

Comment: Descobri: essa linha que você menciona estava comentada por conta do erro...  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/evtTotal/v1_04_00")]  Obrigado

Comment: a instância de var eventos = retornoEnvio?.retornoLoteEventos.retornoEventos?.evento falta um ";" ? 
Eu coloquei, e na linha : 
var retornoEvt = DeserializeFromXmlNode<RetornoTotalizadorEvento.Reinf>(retornoEvtXml); retorna o seguinte erro: 
Erro CS1503 Argumento 1: não é possível converter de "RetornoLoteEventos.TArquivoReinf" para "System.Xml.XmlNode"

Comment: @VagnerCosta, sim, estava faltando um `;` no final daquele linha, e também havia um erro na linha da deserealização, me desculpe. Editei a resposta, veja se agora funciona.

Comment: @VagnerCosta, você conseguiu testar? Agora funcionou?

Comment: consegui sim, deu certo! Muito obrigado! Já tinha sinalizado seu comentário como "útil"!