# Como realizar consulta do Reinf-2099 - ConsultaReciboEvento2099

Tags: c#, web-service

Estou tentando fazer a consulta do ReciboEvento2099, porem não sei a forma correta na documentação fala a URL e o método e também os parâmetros, criei um xml com os parâmetros e estou tentando enviar a requisição, mas sempre obtenho esse erro:

> O servidor remoto retornou um erro: (400) Solicitação Incorreta

O que estou fazendo de errado ou alguém tem um exemplo dessa consulta em C#.

```
public string Consulta(X509Certificate2 cert)
{
    //string xmlRequisicaoSOAP = MontarXmlRequisicao();
    var xmlz = @"wwwroot\reinf\R_2099\consultaFechamento\ReinfLayout_R_2099_Consulta.xml";

    var xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.Load(xmlz);

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"https://preprodefdreinf.receita.fazenda.gov.br/wsreinf/ConsultasReinf.svc");
    request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "http://sped.fazenda.gov.br/ConsultasReinf/ConsultaReciboEvento2099");

    request.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
    request.Accept = "text/xml";
    request.Method = "POST";
    if (cert != null)
        request.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
    if (this.TimeOutEmSegundos > 0)
        request.Timeout = this.TimeOutEmSegundos * 1000;

    this.UltimaRequisicao = xml.OuterXml;

    using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        using (StreamWriter stmw = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            stmw.Write(xml);
        }
    }

    try
    {
        WebResponse webresponse = request.GetResponse();
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webresponse;
        //if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string result = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
            return result;
        }
    }
    catch (WebException wex)
    {
        string mensagemSubjacente = ObterMensagemSubjacente(wex);
        string msg = string.Format("{1}{0}Detalhes subjacentes: {2}",
            System.Environment.NewLine, wex.Message, mensagemSubjacente);

        throw new InvalidOperationException(msg);
        //throw new ExcecaoComunicacaoREINF(msg, wex, xmlRequisicaoSOAP);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
        // throw new ExcecaoComunicacaoREINF(ex.Message, ex, xmlRequisicaoSOAP);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está tentando usar o seguinte `SOAPAction`:

```
"http://sped.fazenda.gov.br/ConsultasReinf/ConsultaReciboEvento2099"
```

Mas, se você acessar o WSDL do serviço em:

> https://preprodefdreinf.receita.fazenda.gov.br/wsreinf/ConsultasReinf.svc?singleWsdl

Você verá que o `SOAPAction` deveria ser:

```
"http://sped.fazenda.gov.br/ConsultasReinf/ConsultaInformacoesConsolidadas"
```

A consulta do evento **R-2099** (*Fechamento dos Eventos Periódicos*) é diferente dos outros eventos do EFD-Reinf. Você deve informar os parâmetros `tipoInscricaoContribuinte`, `numeroInscricaoContribuinte` e `numeroProtocoloFechamento`, diretamente na chamada ao serviço, e receberá como retorno o evento **R-5011** (*Informações de bases e tributos consolidadas por período de apuração*).

Veja um exemplo de consulta ao R-5011 (retorno do R-2099) nessa resposta:

> [Reinf - Erro com evento R-5011 - Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/291189/86952)

Entretanto, essa resposta usa a classe que herda `System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`, gerada ao adicionar uma referência ao serviço, através do Visual Studio, e se você quiser fazer mesmo a comunicação direta do SOAP "na mão" usando `HttpWebRequest` (que dá mais trabalho e não sei se traz algum benefício extra), ao invés de deixar que o .NET cuide disso para você, tem essa outra resposta (que é para o eSocial, mas a ideia é a mesma):

> [Erro 400 ao enviar requisição para o ESocial (C#) - Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/329364/86952)

Lembrando que o XML que você está enviando ao serviço do EFD-Reinf pode ser o problema também, já que ele deve seguir um esquema específico, e deve conter as tags do SOAP, como `envelope` e `body`. Se não conseguir resolver com as dicas que passei, poste o seu XML também na pergunta.

Comment: Obrigado, eu adicionei aqui de acordo com o seu exemplo por wsdl, e consegui realizar a consulta