# Reinf - Consulta ao evento 2099 -fechamento

Tags: c#, web-service

Estou realizando a consulta do Evento de fechamento R2099, baseada na questão:

[Reinf - Erro com evento R-5011](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/290956/reinf-erro-com-evento-r-5011)

Utilizando da mesma forma que o @Pedro Gaspar demonstrou:

```
var urlServicoConsulta = @"https://preprodefdreinf.receita.fazenda.gov.br/ConsultasReinf.svc";
var address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(urlServicoConsulta);
var binding = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpsBinding();  //Disponível desde .NET Framework 4.5
// ou:
//var binding = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport);
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = System.ServiceModel.HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;

// Instancia o cliente para acessar o serviço de consulta do EFD-Reinf.
var wsClient = new WsConsultas.ConsultasReinfClient(binding, address);
wsClient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = x509Cert;

// Solicita uma consulta, passando os parâmetros e recebendo o evento R-5011 como retorno.
System.Xml.Linq.XElement retornoTotalContrib = wsClient.ConsultaInformacoesConsolidadas(1, "10220048", "4308-2099-1701-4308");
wsClient.Close();
```

Na minha chamada:

```
System.Xml.Linq.XElement retornoTotalContrib = wsClient.ConsultaInformacoesConsolidadas(1, "01628604", "15598-2099-1812-15598");
```

Está retornando o seguinte erro:

```
  Message=There was no endpoint listening at https://preprodefdreinf.receita.fazenda.gov.br/ConsultasReinf.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
```

[image: There was no endpoint listening at ...]

O service reference que eu adicionei está apontando para essa url:
https://preprodefdreinf.receita.fazenda.gov.br/WsREINF/ConsultasReinf.svc?singleWsdl

Alguma idéia do que poderia estar ocorrendo?

Comment: Provavelmente seja o cabeçalho `SOAPAction`, veja se está informando o correto: `http://sped.fazenda.gov.br/ConsultasReinf/ConsultaInformacoesConsolidadas`.

Comment: No erro está a url: `https://preprodefdreinf.receita.fazenda.gov.br/ConsultasReinf.svc`, o service reference que você disse que está apontando é: `https://preprodefdreinf.receita.fazenda.gov.br/WsREINF/ConsultasReinf.svc?singleWsdl`. Qual url você deveria utilizar afinal? Tem uma distorção de informações (`WsREINF`) na url...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É isso que você já supôs na própria pergunta e que já responderam mais ou menos nos comentários: O endereço do serviço que usei [naquela resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/291189/86952) estava desatualizado (já atualizei a resposta), os endereços agora são esses:

> *Para o ambiente de Produção Restrita (teste):*
>   https://preprodefdreinf.receita.fazenda.gov.br/WsReinfConsultas/ConsultasReinf.svc
>
> *Para o ambiente de Produção (oficial):*
>   https://reinf.receita.fazenda.gov.br/WsReinfConsultas/ConsultasReinf.svc

Então você tem que atualizar essa linha do código:

```
var urlServicoConsulta =
  @"https://preprodefdreinf.receita.fazenda.gov.br/WsReinfConsultas/ConsultasReinf.svc";
```

Comment: Tem razão. A url que estava no meu service reference também estava desatualizada!